# How to get the resolution of a monitor in Pygame?

Tags: python, window, pygame, resolution, dimensions

I'm just wondering if it is possible for me to get the resolution of a monitor in Pygame and then use these dimensions to create a window so that launching the program detects the monitor resolution and then automatically fits the window to the screen in fullscreen.

I am currently using `pygame.display.set_mode((AN_INTEGER, AN_INTEGER))` to create the window.
I am aware that you can get video info including the monitor resolution using `pygame.display.Info()` but how can I extract these values and then  use them in `pygame.display.set_mode()`???

Thanks in advance,
Ilmiont

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can use `pygame.display.Info()`:

The [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info) say:

> current_h, current_w:  Height and width of the current video mode, or of the
>     desktop mode if called before the display.set_mode is called.
>   (current_h, current_w are available since SDL 1.2.10, and pygame
>   1.8.0)   They are -1 on error, or if an old SDL is being used.1.8.0)

`pygame.display.Info()` creates an Info Object with the attributes `current_h` and `current_w`. 
Create the Info Object before you call `display.set_mode` and then call `display.set_mode` with `current_h` and `current_w` from the object.

**Example:**

```
infoObject = pygame.display.Info()
pygame.display.set_mode((infoObject.current_w, infoObject.current_h))
```

Comment: Good answer, just a note: depending on the OS, the windows may be misaligned to the window.

Answer (score 10):

I don't know if this will work, but if you just want a fullscreen window use the following:

```
pygame.display.set_mode((0,0),pygame.FULLSCREEN)
```

(of course you still have to `import pygame`).

Comment: The one issue with this method is that the actual screen will only take up a miscro part of the scren. So it's not the best solution. However, +1.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know much about pygame, but here is a way using the module `win32api`:

```
from win32api import GetSystemMetrics

width = GetSystemMetrics(0)
height = GetSystemMetrics(1)
```

**Update**: After taking a glance at the [docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.Info), seems like you can get it from `pygame.display.Info`, like this:

```
width, height = pygame.display.Info().current_w, pygame.display.Info().current_h
```

Hope this helps!