# Opening a resizable window in Pygame in Fullscreen

Tags: python, pygame, window

I'm making a firework simulation in pygame, and I want to be able to run the program, and have it open up in full screen. Not the `pygame.FULLSCREEN`, I still want to be able to use `pygame.QUIT`.
I don't know if this is possible, but if anyone could help, please share your ideas!

Here's my code for the screen:

```
import pygame
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0, 0), pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Comment: What is the problem you're having?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the resolution of a monitor in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954469/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-a-monitor-in-pygame)

Answer (score 3):

You could use the width and height of the screen to setup the resolution, like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954469/how-to-get-the-resolution-of-a-monitor-in-pygame), by using the VideoInfo object provided by pygame:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
video_infos = pygame.display.Info()
width, height = video_infos.current_w, video_infos.current_h
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.RESIZABLE)
# [...]
```